# Mudar diretório para HTML entender o src destino

Tags: php, html

tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
/help/
    admin/
            index.php
    imagens/
            botoes/
                    botao1.jpg
                    botao2.jpg
    SISTEMA1/
                    paginas/
                                  pagina1.htm
                                  pagina2.htm
                    imagens/
                                  imagem1.jpg
                                  imagem2.jpg
    SISTEMA2/
                    paginas/
                                  pagina1.htm
                                  pagina2.htm
                    imagens/
                                  imagem1.jpg
                                  imagem2.jpg
    SISTEMA3/...
```

dentro do admin, tenho o `index.php`, nele, eu to pegando o content da `pagina1.htm` que fica na pasta `SISTEMA1/paginas/`
através da função php `file_get_contents()`

**MEU PROBLEMA**

tenho imagens no arquivo `pagina1.htm` com os seguintes `src=""`:

```
src="../imagens/imagem1.jpg"
src="../imagens/botoes/botao1.jpg"
```

a imagem do `botao` aparece, ou seja, eu to dentro do admin no meu `index.php` voltando uma pasta eu vo entra em `imagens` e dentro de imagens tem a pasta `botoes`. Só que a imagem `imagem1.jpg` nao vou encontrar, pq ela ta dentro da pasta `SISTEMA1/imagens`

ou seja, eu precisava encontrar uma forma de resolver isso,kkk, tentei usar o `chdir()` do `PHP` mas não tive sucesso, obrigado

**QUASE RESOLVIDO**

quando eu "printo" a img aparece, mas quando coloco ela dentro de um editor de texto ela nao aparece:

[image: EXEMPLO]

Comment: Você está dentro de **admin**, não é?!, já tentou voltar para a pasta? Ex: `SISTEMA1/../admin/` Não entendi sua pergunta direito, refaça!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar a tag `base`?

Com ela é possível definir a url base para todos os links da página.

Exemplo:

```
<head>
   <base href="http://localhost/pasta/">
</head>
```

Comment: deu certo! mas, quando eu coloco o conteudo em um editor de texto, ele nao mostra aimagem, eu "printando" a imagem normal ela aparece, mas dentro do editor ( estou usando o ckeditor) ela nao aparece, tem algum conflito?